# Performing Segue after Login

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

So I'm designing an application where, like most apps, takes users to the "home page" after a successful login. However, I can't quite figure out how to get it to work. The code for my Login page is as follows:

```
import UIKit

class LoginVC: UIViewController {
@IBOutlet weak var usernameTxt: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var passwordTxt: UITextField!


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

//@IBAction func userLogin(_ sender: AnyObject) {
@IBAction func userLogin(_ sender: AnyObject) {

    // if textboxes are empty
    if usernameTxt.text!.isEmpty || passwordTxt.text!.isEmpty {

        // red placeholders
        usernameTxt.attributedPlaceholder = NSAttributedString(string: "Username", attributes: [NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.red])

        passwordTxt.attributedPlaceholder = NSAttributedString(string: "Password", attributes: [NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.red])


    } else {

        // shortcuts
        let username = usernameTxt.text!.lowercased()
        let password = passwordTxt.text!



        // send request to mysql db
        // Create a user in the mySQL db
        // the exclamation at the end means we insist to launch it
        // url to php file
        let url = NSURL(string: "https://cgi.soic.indiana.edu/~team7/login.php")!

        // request to the file
        let request = NSMutableURLRequest(url: url as URL)

        // method to pass data to this file via the POST method
        request.httpMethod = "POST"

        // what occurs after the question mark in the url
        // body to be appended to url from values in textboxes
        let body = "username=\(username)&password=\(password)"

        // appends body to request that will be sent
        request.httpBody = body.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)

        // launching
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest, completionHandler: { (data:Data?, response:URLResponse?, error:Error?) -> Void in

            if error == nil {

                // get main queue in code process to communicate back
                DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {


                    // do this unless some error which is caught by catch
                    do {
                        // get json result
                        let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .mutableContainers) as? NSDictionary
                        // guard let is the same thing as if let
                        // asign json to new variable in secure way
                        // original guard let used
                        guard let parseJSON = json else {
                            print("Error while parsing")
                            return
                        }

                        // get id from parseJSON dictionary
                        let id = parseJSON["id"] as? String



                        // if there is some id value
                        if id != nil && response != nil {

                            print(parseJSON)

                            // successfully logged in
                            //let userID = parseJSON["id"] as! String
                            //let userN = parseJSON["username"] as! String
                            //let eMail = parseJSON["email"] as! String
                            //print(parseJSON["username"] ?? String.self)
                            //let myVC = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "RetrievalVC") as! RetrievalVC
                            //myVC.id_Outlet.text = userID
                            //myVC.full_Outlet.text = userN
                            //myVC.email_Outlet.text = eMail
                            //
                            //self.navigationController?.pushViewController(myVC, animated: true)


                        }



                    } catch {
                        print("Caught an error \(error)")
                    }
                })
                                    // if unable to process request
            } else {
                print("error: \(error)")
            }

        }).resume()
        //performSegue(withIdentifier: "loginSuccess", sender: LoginVC.self)
    }


}
}
```

I am trying to use

```
performSegue(withIdentifier: "loginSuccess", sender: LoginVC.self)
```

In order to perform the segue but I'm not sure where in the code it should go.
Any suggestions or changes I need to make to the code?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on back end logic.I assume that parseJSON["id"] is returned only if user is verified. So you can use this

```
let id = parseJSON["id"] as? String

  // if there is some id value
   if id != nil {
    // perform segue here
}
```

Comment: you can perform a segue when error is nil and you are response contains data...
 

if id != nil && response != nil {
performSegue(withIdentifier: "loginSuccess", sender: LoginVC.self)
}

Comment: If you only check that error is nil and response contains some data then unauthorized user can get access to app, because if in case error is nil and in response there is message that "incorrect user name or password"

Comment: "incorrect user name or password" this is the error message not the response data.. I am talking about the response data..

Comment: You can check in completion handler of code there is parameter error:Error in this errors are returned like "request time out" not the error message returned from server. Error messages returned from server will return in response.

Comment: response comes in a object from server  which contains  
{ status 
   data
   error
} and response.data is not nil then play with the login segue..

Comment: When I put the perform segue below if id != nil, I get an error saying that "Value of type 'LoginVC' has no member 'LoginVC'". I think the problem is the 'self'. Any suggestions?

Comment: perform segue like this : self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "loginSuccess", sender: nil)  and also make sure you have set identifier of segue in storyboard.

Answer (score 0):

You can perform a segue when error is `nil` and you are response contains data...

```
 if id != nil && response != nil {
    performSegue(withIdentifier: "loginSuccess", sender: LoginVC.self)
 }
```

Comment: When I used this snippet of code, I received an error saying "Implicit use of 'self' in closure, use 'self.' to make capture semantics explicit". Any suggestions?